# not able to access the loggedIn value of express.session in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, sequelize.js

I have created a web app with the help of nodejs . I am using sequelize as the ORM for mysql.
Now I have implemented log in functionality with the help of expression-session. However the loggedIn parameter returns undefined whenever I try to access it in different routes.

My AppJs File:

```
const path=require('path');
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session= require('express-session');
const sequelize= require('./util/database');
var SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);
const myStore=new SequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize,
  })
app.use(session({secret:'my secret',  store:myStore ,resave:false,saveUninitialized:false}))


app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.set('views', 'views');


const movieroutes=require('./routes/movies');
const personroutes=require('./routes/persons');
const testroutes=require('./routes/test');
const authroutes=require('./routes/auth');



const Movie= require('./models/movie');
const Moviegenre=require('./models/moviegenre');
const Person=require('./models/person');
const Personrole=require('./models/personrole');
const Personmovierole=require('./models/personmovierole');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use("/",movieroutes);
app.use("/",personroutes);
app.use("/",testroutes);
app.use("/",authroutes);


var port=3000||process.env.PORT
app.listen(port,function(){
   console.log("the server has started");
})
app.use("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./','views','home.html'));
})

Person.belongsToMany(Movie,{through:Personmovierole,unique:false});
Movie.belongsToMany(Person,{through:Personmovierole,unique:false});
Person.belongsToMany(Personrole,{through:Personmovierole,unique:false});
Personrole.belongsToMany(Person,{through:Personmovierole,unique:false});
Movie.belongsToMany(Personrole,{through:Personmovierole,unique:false});
Personrole.belongsToMany(Movie,{through:Personmovierole,unique:false});


myStore.sync();
sequelize.
sync().
then(result=>{
    console.log(`sync done`);
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
})
```

My Auth Controller:

```
exports.getLogin= (req,res,next)=>
{
  
    res.render('auth/login',{
       isAuthenticated:false
       
    })

}


exports.postLogin= (req,res,next)=>

{
    req.session.isLoggedIn=true;
    console.log(req.session.isLoggedIn);
    req.session.save(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect('/');
        
    })
  

}

exports.postLogout= (req,res,next)=>

{ 
    req.session.destroy(err=> {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect('/');
    });



}
```

My Movie controller:

```
exports.getAllMovies=(req,res,next)=>{
    Movie.findAll()
    .then(movies=>{
      console.log(req.session);
      console.log(req.session.IsLoggedIn);
        res.render('movies',{
            movies:movies,
            isAuthenticated:req.session.IsLoggedIn
            
        });
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });

    
};
```

As you can see in the movie controller. I have inserted two console.log values.

the `console.log(req.session)` returns :

`Session { cookie: { path: '/', _expires:null,originalMaxAge:null,httpOnly: true }, isLoggedIn: true}`

however `console.log(req.session.IsLoggedIn)` returns :

`undefined`

Pleae help

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: `isLoggedIn` not `IsLoggedIn`

`req.session.Session(isLoggedIn)`

`Session { cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAgenull,httpOnly:true}, isLoggedIn: true }`